# Distributed connection pool for Oracle database

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, database-connection, connection-pooling

We are working on moving a monolithic solution to AWS cloud and use serverless technology to run it (AWS lambdas).
However database is becoming a bottleneck for scalability and we want to utilise our DB connections lot more efficiently so we are looking for a distributed connection pooling solutions. Without a distributed connection pool, our scaling capability will be very limited.

We have done some research and one option of "AWS RDS proxy" but this requires use of AWS RDS DB which is not feasible for us.

Any suggestions on alternative solutions or design for this.

Answer (score 0):

Under serverless, connection sharing should not be possible. It can be considered that database access is forwarded to a traditional service, but this violates the original intention of no service. Whether to consider using memory databases such as redis to control the number of connections, and the application side Capabilities such as connection waiting beyond the upper limit may be feasible